# sql check for duplicates returning bool false?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an php/ sql function that I am using to store values in a database and I would like to use an if statement to check if the value already exists in a column.

Heres my code thus far:

```
<?php

$fbname = $_POST['fbname'];
$fbemail = $_POST['fbemail'];
$checkdupe = "SELECT Email from userregtable where Email=$fbemail";

if (mysql_num_rows($checkdupe) >= 1) {
    echo "no!";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userregtable (Name, Email) VALUES ('$fbname', '$fbemail') ";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

I had an error with this code that said:

> mysql_num_rows expects exactly 1 parameter

when I removed the if statement to see what the `$checkdupe` query was returning through a var_dump it said `bool=false`. First I intentionally tried to add an entry that already existed so I'mm not sure why it says false, secondly I would have thought it would have returned a numeric value not `bool=false`... I copied this from a tutorial online and have been over it several times so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: mysql_query is missing. Please refer [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'v forgotten to call `mysql_query` first. Also you missed quotes near `$fbemail` in select statement:

```
<?php
$checkdupe = mysql_query("SELECT Email from userregtable where Email='$fbemail'");
```

Alternative approach is to add `Email` into unique key of table and do insert with `IGNORE` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE userregtable ADD UNIQUE (Email);
INSERT IGNORE INTO userregtable (Name, Email) VALUES ('$fbname', '$fbemail');
```

INSERT IGNORE work only if there is no constraint violation.

P.S. Escape you data with `mysql_real_escape_string` to prevent SQL-injection atack.

```
<?php

$checkdupe = mysql_query('SELECT Email from userregtable where Email="' . mysql_real_escape_string($fbemail) . '"');
mysql_query('
  INSERT INTO userregtable (Name, Email) 
  VALUES (
  "' . mysql_real_escape_string($fbname) . '", 
  "' . mysql_real_escape_string($fbemail) . '"
  )
');
```

P.S.2 To clarify error, you may use:

```
<?php echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";
```

after the first `mysql_query`.

Comment: ok I added in the query as you mentioned above but now I am getting a message saying mysql_num_rows expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in. Any idea why? Also Do I even need a real escape string if I am grabbing the variables from the facebook API?

Comment: Have u added quotes near `$fbemail`? Is db connection ok?

Yes, you need escape data when form queries this way. It's rule of thumb.

Comment: Yes DB connect is fine. Its actually writing the entry in every time. And yes I also added in the quotes

Comment: Try to debug you sql with `<?php echo("SELECT Email from userregtable where Email='$fbemail'"); exit;` Grab it from browser and run sql-query directly to sql-server.

Comment: I ran echo("SELECT Email from userregtable where Email='$fbemail'"); exit; in the php file but it just echos the entire query line written above. I wrote SELECT Email from userregtable where Email='$fbemail'; in the sql server (without the email variable but with the actual email im using) and it returns all the entries

Comment: mysql_num_rows says that mysql_query returns bool instead of resourse. It means that there is error in query, db connection or user rights (almost incredibly for select statement :) )  Did you added mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: the error must lie in the query. It writes every time to the database as it should, it just doesnt check for duplicates before writing.

Comment: And yes real escape string

Comment: Try to compose your query into `$sql` variable and echo it to browser. Result should be ready to be inserted into sql-server. If not, check errors. Recheck quotes, database and column names etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95980/discussion-between-ben-liger-and-userlond).

Comment: came down to the db user permissions being able to insert but not select! Amended priveledges and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

First, please consider using `mysqli_`, or even better, look into PDO.

That being said, you need to actually query your `SELECT` statement. Try changing your `$checkdupe` variable to match the following:

> $checkdupe = mysql_query("SELECT...");

I didn't do any testing, but that should solve your issue.

Comment: ok I added in the query as you mentioned above but now I am getting a message saying mysql_num_rows expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in. Any idea why?

Comment: @BenLiger, check my answer